# Node.js Socket.io maximum listeners

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket.io + Express.js for real time communication for my application. As of now I have 30 listeners `(socket.on('eventName', () => {}))` in our server side which are listening to events. I have couple of question here, which I could not find relevant answer.

**Question 1:** How many listeners at max, we can have for single socket connection?

I knew that socket.io events were built on top of Event Emitter class. It stores all events callback functions in the global object and when someone emit with event name, it searches for the event name in the object and just execute the respective callback function for the event. I believe all these functions are getting stored in in-memory in the socket connection object.

**Question 2:** I have few listeners from my client(react) side as well. Let's say if I have 20 listeners from server side and 10 listeners from client side. When socket connection was made, where these client listeners callback functions are getting stored? Is it stored in browser side or in server-side socket object?

**Question 3**: Will there be a problem if I have a greater number of event listeners? If so, then what is maximum safe limit?

Thanks for the help in advance.